# Is the vuetify main.sass bundle file size of 30kb gzipped normal?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

Title says it all basically:

Is the file size normal? Does it include all component stylings even if removed by treeshaking?

Treeshaking enabled.

Any advice is very much appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at this [github issue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/13724), it looks perfectly normal to them.

I guess that not everything is tree-shakable, especially with CSS. It looks like you can disable some properties with something like this: https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/12512#issuecomment-716729391

But yeah, mainly don't expect much from Vuetify if you want to have a smaller bundle size IMO.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Appreciate it!
Does vuetify have a bad reputation in terms of bundle size or is it just the tradeoff when using component libraries? What about quasar in comparison for example?

Comment: I don't think that any component libraries will have a small bundle size. Either use an utility CSS framework (like Tailwind) or just some component with the least amount of style applied to it (like HeadlessUI, only Vue3-tho) if you really want to have a small footprint. It requires a bit of work but you can't have both. This one may be a good alternative too maybe? https://lion-web.netlify.app/ (handles a11y too) At the end, try them all and quickly look at the webpack analyzer to find one with which you're satisfied or try to tinker them to minimize their size if you don't like utility ones